# Handle dialog-close event on input type='color'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a default(*html5*) color selector:

```
<input id='color-picker' type=color value='#ff0000'>
```

By click on the element, a default color-picker dialog opens.
I can easily track the color change event:

```
$('#color-picker').on('change', function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

How dialog window close event can be handled? For example, when user clicks **Cancel** button?
Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enx9k3xz/) additionally.

Comment: Does it fire blur?

Comment: @epascarello blur fires event on simple click, because new window opens, and the focus on DOM element losts. So that`s not about 'blur'

Comment: I saw solution to a similar dialog of file uploading here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855400/cancel-event-on-input-type-file , but that solution looks quite heavy. :\

Comment: In terms of events which can be attched/tracked in regards to input type color, you can only use "input" and "change" - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#color-state-(type=color)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the exact functionality is not possible. I even read through the stack link, it seems that file calls the `change` event regardless of change, whereas color does not... So, I added the code to the blur event instead.  When the user click off the value after editing color for any reason, it will check for cancel.  I added a phony submit button to force the user to do it.

```js
$('#color-picker').on('blur', function() {
  if ($(this).data("prevColor") == $(this).val()) {
    console.log('cancelled');
  } else {
    //value changed
  }
  updateData.bind(this)();
});

function updateData() {
  $(this).data("prevColor", $(this).val());
}

updateData.bind($("#color-picker"))();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='color-picker' type=color value='#ff0000'><button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Well, that`s a possible way, but far not the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this for the Cancel and Close Events.

```js
    var prevColor;
    $('#color-picker').onchange = function(){
        if (this.value != prevColor){
          prevColor = this.value;
        }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='color-picker' type=color value='#ff0000'><button>Submit</button>
```