# Is it possible to implement a promise-based file picker API in JavaScript / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Goal:

1. Programmatic: Call the API function, it will create `<input>` element and invoke file picker dialog.
2. Promise-based: If there're files selected, resolve with array of files. If user cancel the dialog, resolve with empty array or reject.

My current implementation:

```js
let input: HTMLInputElement
let lastPromiseResolve: (files: File[]) => void

const defaultConfig = {
  accept: '*',
  multiple: false,
}

export const pickFile = async (config: Partial<typeof defaultConfig> = defaultConfig) => {
  const { accept, multiple } = { ...defaultConfig, ...config }
  if (!input) {
    input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = 'file'
    input.style.display = 'none'
    document.body.appendChild(input)
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
      lastPromiseResolve?.([...input.files])
      lastPromiseResolve = null
    })
  }
  input.accept = accept
  input.multiple = multiple
  input.value = ''
  // resolve with empty array for previous calls
  if (lastPromiseResolve) {
    lastPromiseResolve([])
  }
  const files = await new Promise<File[]>(resolve => {
    lastPromiseResolve = resolve
    input.click()
  })
  return files
}
```

The problem is when user cancel the dialog, `change` / `input` events are not fired. So the promise is not resolved nor rejected unless I call `pickFile` for the second time.

There is also a similar npm package [js-pick-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-pick-file), having [the same problem](https://github.com/arpit9295/js-pick-file/issues/1).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855400/cancel-event-on-input-type-file

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy Tried solutions from that question. Because the script clicks the input element instead of user, `focus` / `blur` are never fired. (for Chrome 89 in Windows)