# How can I handle click on file input with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file, input, vuejs2

I want to handle the cancel press when uploading a file

[image]

I looked at some examples that were implemented using pure JavaScript here is an [example](https://itsopensource.com/handle-cancel-click-on-file-input/)

All these examples work fine, I tried to implement this example using Vue JS, but it does not work correctly for me

```
<div>
   <label for="upload" @click="initialize">Upload File</label>
   <input type="file" id="upload" ref="theFile" hidden />
</div>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      document.body.onfocus = this.checkIt;
      alert("initializing");
    },

    checkIt() {
      if (this.$refs.theFile.value.length) alert("Files Loaded");
      else alert("Cancel clicked");
      document.body.onfocus = null;
      alert("checked");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You can see an example of [my code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-euler-6jlc3)

Comment: Protip: use something other than alerts. [They should be avoided](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/should-alert-boxes-be-avoided-at-any-cost).

Comment: afaik there's no event you can use for that. what is the use case? relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34855400/10975709

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there isn't an event to capture canceling and you would be better off just adding a submit button.

Having said that, [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-pond-gjogq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) will tell you if files were uploaded when the next 'mouseenter' event is fired on the body. It won't tell you if the cancel button was clicked.

```
<template>
  <form>
    <label for="upload">Upload File</label>
    <input
      @click="onShowFileUpload"
      @change="onFileUpload"
      type="file"
      id="upload"
      ref="theFile"
      hidden
    />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onShowFileUpload() {
      this.$refs.theFile.value = "";
      const onHandleMouseEnter = () => {
        if (this.$refs.theFile.value.length === 0) {
          console.log("No files loaded");
        }
        document.body.removeEventListener("mouseenter", onHandleMouseEnter);
      };
      document.body.addEventListener("mouseenter", onHandleMouseEnter);
    },
    onFileUpload(event) {
      console.log("Files Uploaded");
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: this might not work in some cases where keyboard navigation was used. point is, if you have something **important** to do, don't rely on hacks like this and you might be approaching the problem the wrong way. if not, then you're fine.

Comment: You are right, I just discovered this problem today that you highlighted